# Get value of battery level OpenNetCF 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6, opennetcf

I'm working on windows mobile 6.0 project using .NET CF and OpenNET CF.
I'm looking to get the value of the battery from the battery life bar.
Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

The 2.0 version of the SDF is really old and I don't know if it contained the classes specific for power monitoring.

If the old 1.4 code base, there is a control called the `BatteryLife` which can show the power level.  The source for that control (which is simple) contains all of the P/Invokes to get the info.

The newer 2.3 code base has a PowerStatus class that gives the information you want.

You could also choose to directly P/Invoke yourself

```
[DllImport("codedll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetSystemPowerStatusEx2(
    PowerStatus pStatus, int dwLen, bool fUpdate);
```